# How to remove class from TD in table by clicking on button/Div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, removeclass

here i want to remove a specific class from a `<td><td>` inside table and i have a another table in which i have a button and by clicking on this button i want to remove class of `<td><td>` which is in different table.

My HTML is As Like

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td class="background"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="background"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="background"></td>
    <td class="background"></td>
    <td class="background"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="Close">
        <span>Click Me</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery Code am trying is

```
$("#Close").click(function () {
    $('#test', 'tr','td').removeClass("background");
});
```

Comment: `$('#test td').removeClass('background');`

Comment: do you want to remove one specific td or all? if all try `$('.background').removeClass('background');`

Comment: i tried something like `$('td').removeClass('background');` that is also working

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#Close").click(function () {
    $('#test td').removeClass("background");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test td').removeClass('background');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
document.getElementById('tdid').className = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#Close").click(function() {
  $('.background').removeClass("background");
});
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td class="background">1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="background">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="background">1</td>
    <td class="background">1</td>
    <td class="background">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="Close">
        <span>Click Me</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to remove all then select the class then remove that class.

Comment: @Learner glad to help mate